# Porous materials: Is the expression of a mean free path $\overline{\ell}$ of the gas molecule valid for a binary mixtures?

Tags: molecular-structure, molecules, adsorption, diffusion

Suppose that I have a binary gas mixture at low pressure. Can I calculate the mean free path $\overline{\ell}$ of the gas molecule in a pores of solid material by substituting a molecular weight of a single component by Molecular weight of the binary mixture $M_{m,\rm mix}$ as well as the specific gas constant of this mixture $R_{\rm mix}$, such that I get:

\begin{equation}
\overline{\ell} \:=\: \dfrac{3.2\cdot \mu_g}{p}\cdot \left(\dfrac{R_{\rm mix}\cdot T_{\rm abs}}{2\pi\cdot M_{m,\rm mix}}\right)\:\:\:\rm\left[m\right]
\end{equation}

I am calculating $\overline{\ell}$ in order to determine the main diffusion mechanism in the pores (Bulk diffusion (Fick), Knudsen or its combination).

Comment: What is the size of pores ? Is is much greater than the mean free pass in a free gas ?

Comment: Mean radius of the pore is $R_p = 8\cdot 10^{-9}\:\left[\rm m\right]$. If used the equation above for the mixture, then the ratio is $\sim 0.725$, which would suggest a combination of Fick' and Knudsen diffusion. However, when I determined a Knudsen number $\rm Kn = \overline{\ell}\big/ d_p$, I obtained $\rm Kn > 10$, which would suggest Knudsen diffusion to be dominant.